# O que seria e como utilizar NameVirtualHost *:80?

Tags: htaccess, apache

Estou a instalar um novo site pré configurado, mas para que ele possa ser instalado é preciso criar um arquivo de configuração da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa parte na documentação está vaga pra mim, e não entendi o que seria esse arquivo de configuração, criei então um arquivo .htaccess na pasta htdocs do xampp.

Meu arquivo ficou assim:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost;
  DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\public;
</VirtualHost>
```

Mas quando tento acessar http://localhost vejo este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Também tentei utilizar modificando o código para isto:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost;
  DocumentRoot /xampp/htdocs/public;
</VirtualHost>
```

Mas o erro gerado é o mesmo. O que estou fazendo de errado? Segue estrutura dos diretórios htdocs e public respectivamente.

[image: htdocs]

[image: publick]

Comment: Com o `VirtualHost` você pode apontar pastas e portas, fazendo ajustes para cada tipo de acesso, também é possivel detectar o HOST, ou seja poderá usar multiplos HOSTs e cada HOST teria sua propria pasta de apontamento.

Comment: obrigada, mas ele deve ser adicionado ao .htaccess mesmo? pois estou fazendo um teste excluindo esse código que coloquei aqui na pergunta e o erro é o mesmo, parece que é indiferente se está ou não no .htaccess

Comment: Não, virtualhost não funciona no htaccess, o controle do virtualhost é no core, o htaccess executa bem depois da execução de checagem do host atual.

Comment: Talnun vai nos logs do Apache por favor e tenta copiar os erros e me manda, pode ser algum módulo ou loop de redirecionamento infinito.